# Angular, Typescript accessing nested model as array

Tags: arrays, angular, nested, typescript2.0

trying to access the child member(is an array) of parent interface.
But getting `undefined`.

```
export class Address {
    id: number;
    city: string;
    state: string;
}

import { Address } from './address';
export class User {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    alladdresses: Address[];
}
```

in my component - the declaration are

```
  users: User[] = [];
  address: Address[] = [];
```

and my `http.get` is

```
    selectUser(user: User) {
    let url = "http://localhost:8080/users/" + user.id
    this.http.get<User>(url).subscribe(

      res => {
        //console.log(res);
        this.selectedUser = res;
        console.log('selected user is:', this.selectedUser);

      },
      error => {
        console.log('error while getting user for ', user.id);
      },
      () => {
        console.log('complete');
      }
    );
  }
```

and the json response of user is
[image]

here the selected user I am displaying on the page, and some action on page calling another function to access the addresses - the array

```
createAddress() {
    let newAddress: Address = {
      id: null,
      city: "new city",
      state: "new state"
    }
    console.log(this.selectedUser)
    let address: Address[] = this.selectedUser.alladdresses
    //address.push(newAddress);
    console.log(address);
  }
```

But the array is undefined, not where waht going wrong.
[image]

Comment: Shouldn't you have `this.selectedUser.addresses` instead of `this.selectedUser.alladdresses` in your `console.log`?

Comment: Unless you want to manually instantiate the class instances, you should define server response types as interfaces.

Comment: all confusion with alladdresses: Address[]; now I have changed to addresses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there's a mismatch between the data your `http.get` method is returning and what you are expecting. Your api is returning the addresses named as `addresses` whereas you are expected `alladdresses`.

Comment: all confusion with alladdresses: Address[]; now I have changed to addresses

Comment: this helped me out. great stuff